# calculation of top 20 Percentile in Redshift/SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract top 20 percentile of the products sold based on the page view count. Is there any direct function in redshift?

Need Suggestions

Sales Query:

```
SELECT product_category,
           product_id,
           sum(page_views) as page_views,
           sum(units) as total_units
           
   FROM order o
   JOIN product p 
               ON p.product_id=o.product_id
   JOIN page_views f
               ON f.product_id=o.product_id
   WHERE 
        extract (year from order_date) =2019  
        and extract (month from order_date) =12 
        and product_category='electronics'
   GROUP BY 
            1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the [`PERCENT_RANK`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_PERCENT_RANK.html) window function which you would run on sum(page_views) and it would tell you what is the rank in percentage. Then you could filter on `pct_rnk <= 0.2`. I think you would need to use CTE to do the filtering though - you cannot filter on the results of a window function

Something like (I did not test it):

```
WITH ranked_products as (
SELECT product_category,
           product_id,
           PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sum(page_views) desc) as pct_rnk
           
 FROM order o
 JOIN product p 
             ON p.product_id=o.product_id
 JOIN page_views f
             ON f.product_id=o.product_id
 WHERE 
      extract (year from order_date) =2019  
      and extract (month from order_date) =12 
      and product_category='electronics'
 GROUP BY 1, 2 )
SELECT * FROM ranked_products
WHERE pct_rnk <= 0.2
```